# ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission is not autocompleted

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete, google-play-services, android-manifest

I want to use the ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
However when i type

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.ACTI
```

Android Studio doesn't autocomplete this to

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
```

Is that a problem? why wouldn't it autocomplete? how can i solve this issue?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

Following the instruction in the [**`ActivityRecognition`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition) document and the [How to Recognize User Activity With Activity Recognition](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-recognize-user-activity-with-activity-recognition--cms-25851) tutorial.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this permission in menifest file com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"